# The CGI PATH_INFO variable can really contain control characters?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, cgi

From the [CGI specification, section 4.1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.5), I get that:

```
PATH_INFO = "" | ( "/" path )
path      = lsegment *( "/" lsegment )
lsegment  = *lchar
lchar     = <any TEXT or CTL except "/">
```

where `TEXT` and `CTL` is defined above in the specification:

```
CTL           = <any control character>
TEXT          = <any printable character>
```

now the question is coming, how can control characters in PATH_INFO?

Since PATH_INFO is populated by www server according to the URI entered by user, how we enter control characters in the web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percent-encoding can be used to enter any character in a URL:

```
http://www.example.com/foo%03bar.html
```

This will have a <kbd>Ctl-c</kbd> character between `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Such a fast reply! Thanks very much! I'm sorry, but could I bother you again? Could you explain the difference between PATH_INFO of `""` and of "/", since the specification said that `A PATH_INFO of "/" represents a single void path segment.`

Comment: And also, the specification states that `Unlike a URI path, the PATH_INFO is not URL-encoded, and cannot contain path-segment parameters.`, so if the PATH_INFO is not URL-encoded, how can it contain escaped control characters?

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how you would get an empty string. When I google "empty path_info cgi", most of the hits are about a problem in ColdFusion 10 where it leaves this out.

Comment: What it means is that it's the result of decoding the URL-encoded characters, it doesn't contain the original encoding. See the example in the section on `PATH_INFO_TRANSLATED`.